# AWS PHP SDK Transfer item from one bucket to another in a different region

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I have setup the S3Client with the credentials of an IAM user that can access both buckets in eu-west-1 and ap-southeast-2.

I then use the copy function, with correct fromB, fromK, destB and destK

I receive the error:

> Encountered a permanent redirect while requesting
> https://facelivenesscheck.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/users/12076/144eb60c-c4f0-4919-96ce-bf361766fxxx/reference.jpg.
> Are you sure you are using the correct region for this bucket?

So basically this is showing that for the source, it's constructed the URL and it's looking in the region ap-southeast-2... but the source is in eu-west-1.

How can I specify the source region for the transfer? From what I've read, as long as you use the destination S3Client, then this should just work. But it's not.

Here is the code snippet:

```
private S3Client $userImagesS3;

$this->userImagesS3 = new S3Client([
        'version'     => 'latest',
        'region'      => $region, // region being 'ap-southeast-2'
        'credentials' => new Credentials('xxx', 'xxx')
    ]);


$this->userImagesS3->copy('facelivenesscheck', "users/{$user->id}/{$sessionID}/reference.jpg", $this->s3_bucket,"users/{$user->id}/faceliveness_reference.jpg", "BucketOwnerFullControl");
```

So it's moving it from facelivenesscheck bucket which is in eu-west-1, the reference image. And moving it to s3_bucket which is is ap-southeast-2.

Comment: Are you using `CopyObject`? Would you like to add the relevant code into the question?

Comment: Thanks. I've added code snippet, but there isn't really much to it. It's just initialising the objects and then calling the method.